# Inject env var for all ConfigMap values

Tags: kubernetes

I am searching for a way where i can inject env variable value to configmap
so by defining LOG_SEVERITY as part of my deployment as env variable the value will be automatilcy injected to the configmap.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  log.properties: |
    timeout=10
    severity=${LOG_SEVERITY}
```

Comment: To understand better can you explain why do you want to pass this value as a variable. What problem are you trying to solve here ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use some kind of templating tool to process the YAML. Helm is popular (though that doesn't directly handle environment variables). For your case I would strongly recommend envsubst, it will handle this case nicely.

Comment: Yes I am using helm but the question how in run time the value will be changed , is helm talking care to do the evaluate and replacement, can you please provide simple example of this usage

Answer (score 0):

Like [@coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger) mentioned you can use `envsubst` and [`Helm`](https://helm.sh/). I'll just provide tad more details and a another way ;)

**envsubst**

In your `config_map.yml` you would have:

```
severity= $LOG_SEVERITY
```

Then just create new environmental variable and execute `kubectl` in a following way:

```
export LOG_SEVERITY="9"
envsubst < config_map.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Helm**

Create a [template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#a-first-template) and [calling it](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#adding-a-simple-template-call).

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  log.properties: |
    timeout=10
    severity= {{ .Values.logSeverity }}
```

You would need to define a default value of `severity` inside `mychart/values.yaml`

```
logSeverity: 1
```

And setting a different value by adding `--set` flag to the helm call.

`helm install --set logSeverity=9 ./mychart`

This is nicely explained inside Helm documentation [The Chart Template Developer’s Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/).
Keep in mind this is way more complicated to just use helm as a wrapper for Kubernetes files.

**sed**

`sed -i 's/$LOG_SEVERITY/9/g' input.txt`

I recommend reading [How to use sed to find and replace text in files in Linux / Unix shell](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/).